# Pre populate action form Alfresco share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have an action which is showing a form for some user input. The inputs are plain text field. I wonder how can I pre fill the input field.

All the tutorials and blog posts I found are quite old and all of them are taking into account only one field. It is my understanding that I need a custom .ftl with a call to a web script in it.

```
<field id="myprop">
   <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/mycustomfield.ftl"/>
</field>
```

The problem in my case is that I will end up doing at least six call to the same web script. Because that's the number of fields I currently have in my form.

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess it could be implemented by using a form filter as well. Maybe not the nicest solution, but it should get the job done. https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms_Developer_Guide#Form_Filter

Comment: As a final resource I was just taking a look at FormFilter. I will keep an eye on this. And come back with a feedback.

Comment: Although this could be the cleanest way, it is unfortunately not suitable for Actions. The filter simply never get called. See this question I post on Alfresco forum: [Form Filter not being called](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/formfilter-not-being-called-action-03152015)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one better way... You don't need to use Share Form Engine. Take a look at "create site" dialog, this form doesn't use share form engine

You need to create custom share component that will return form with filled parameters and initialize this form in your front-end js that is executed while clicking on the action.

You can add new component to Share by the following way:

1) Create new descriptor my-form.get.desc.xml in web-extension/site-webscripts/com/pizdez/form

```
<webscript>
  <shortname>my-form</shortname>
  <description>Get HTML form</description>
  <url>/pizdec/components/form</url>
</webscript>
```

2) Create new controller my-form.get.js in the same folder where you can call alfresco to get all needed information

```
var connector = remote.connect("alfresco");
    var response = connector.get("/my/alfresco/webscript");

    if (response.status == 200)
    {
        // Create javascript objects from the repo response
        var obj = eval('(' + response + ')');
        if (obj)
        {
            model.param1 = obj.param1;

        }
    }
```

3) Create ftl template my-form.get.html.ftl in the same folder

```
    <@markup id="css" >
    <#-- CSS Dependencies -->
        <@link href="${url.context}/res/components/form/my.css" />
    </@>

    <@markup id="js">
        <@script src="${url.context}/res/components/form/my.js" />
    </@>

    <@markup id="widgets">
        <@createWidgets/>
    </@>

    <@markup id="html">
        <@uniqueIdDiv>
        <#assign el=args.htmlid?html>
<div id="${el}-dialog">
    <div class="hd">TITLE</div>
    <div class="bd">
        <form id="${el}-form" method="POST" action="">

            <div class="yui-gd">
                <div class="yui-u first"><label for="${el}-title">Title:</label></div>
                <div class="yui-u"><input id="${el}-title" type="text" name="title" tabindex="0" maxlength="255"/>&nbsp;*
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="yui-gd">
                <div class="yui-u first"><label for="${el}-param1">Param1:</label></div>
                <div class="yui-u"><input id="${el}-param1" type="text" name="title" tabindex="0" maxlength="255" value="${param1}"/>&nbsp;*
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bdft">
                <input type="submit" id="${el}-ok-button" value="${msg("button.ok")}" tabindex="0"/>
                <input type="button" id="${el}-cancel-button" value="${msg("button.cancel")}" tabindex="0"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
        </@>
    </@>
```

4) After that you need to get this component from ui js

```
                var myForm = new Alfresco.module.SimpleDialog(this.id + "-dialog");

            myForm.setOptions(
                {
                    width: "50em",
                    templateUrl: Alfresco.constants.URL_SERVICECONTEXT + "/pizdec/components/form",
                    actionUrl: null,
                    destroyOnHide: true,
                    doBeforeDialogShow:
                    {
                        fn: doBeforeDialogShow,
                        scope: this
                    },
                    onSuccess:
                    {
                        fn: function (response)
                        {

                        },
                        scope: this
                    },
                    onFailure:
                    {
                        fn: function(response)
                        {

                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
                }).show();
```

I just wanted to show you direction to research

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by custom share component ? Can you point out to some tutorial or blog post ? Currently my knowledge about Alfresco covers: Custom model, Behaviour, Action, Workflows. I am using Alfresco 4.2.

Comment: Look Leonardo, this isn't the place to ask tutorials. There are multiple topics here and on the Alfresco form. The new Alfresco 5.0 documentation contains valuable samples. Just read away and take a couple of months to get to know Alfresco.

Comment: Don't be so rude, I have already stated that I am using 4.2, and I found normal to ask for links, tutorials, whatever or blog when little information is provided. There are many answers which supply links to external resources.